# Can you get extra exp from Crit/Combo Kills?

Tags: destiny

in some games it's possible to get extra exp from multi-kills or Crit kills, is it possible for Destiny?

I tried some testing in the Intro level: The Dregs give +20 exp, and the Vandals give +35 exp.

I tried doing some testing with combo kills, (*x* enemies in *y* seconds), and Critical kills (headshot kills, all head shots), but I couldnt figure out any patterns.

Is it possible?

Comment: not going to give this an answer, but there are no PVE (not crucible) bonuses for multi-kills. There are however some in PVP (Crucuble), I have gotten a few here and there.

Comment: From observation I would have to say no. I have never gotten anything but the usual XP from any mob, and I've done a fair amount of headshots and critical hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PvE there's no such feature.

A Dreg always give 20 experience points, even if you've leveled way past the level of the area/mob. Same with a Vandal which gives 35 as you say. It doesn't matter how you kill the mob, critical hit or not, super-attack or not, you'll get 20 for the Dreg and 35 for the Vandal just the same.

In PvP you can get some combos, but they don't give XP per se, they give points for the match, and here you can get bonus points if you kill more than one player in a short timespan.

Comment: However, before the last update there was combo kills. I noted, on Earth that killing enemies in succession would bring up a rampage tally with a timer for your combo. Still trying to work it out.

Comment: I've never seen that.

Comment: I haven't since the update.

Comment: You sure this isn't equivalent to the Surge bonus Warlocks get? ie. a class-specific thing? Perhaps you changed your skillset?

Comment: Hunter, maybe possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a high-level Warlock, my Hunter and Titan is still in their infancy so I have no idea. If there is such a bonus that follows some specific skills, they belong in the answer.

Comment: When, I have time to work it out. Not my answer. Anyone?

Comment: So, I checked it out, my bad. Sunslinger class has a skill to level up ammo reload that stacks while active.